# imagick getImageLength not working after crop image

Tags: php, image, imagick

I wanna crop a part of image and then upload the part to other server.
I must make sure that the size of image I upload is below 300k.

```
$image = new Imagick( $path );
echo $image->getImageLength();

$image->cropImage( $image->getImageWidth(), $image->getImageHeight() / 4, 0, 0 );

echo $image->getImageLength();
```

the first time i get image size with $image->getImageLength() return a correct value of the image.
but it returns 0 while i get image size after cropImage.

How can I get correct value after i process the image ? I want to know whether it is small enough to be uploaded.

Comment: There has to be something more going on. You should check to make sure `$image->getImageWidth()` and `$image->getImageHeight()` are producing non zero numbers. Then check to make sure `$image->getImageHeight()/4` is greater than zero.

Comment: Feel free to post an example image that does this, with a complete code example. Until then I think you have a mistake in your code.

Comment: @Whitecat  . at last i use strlen( $image->getImageBlob() ) to get image file size instead.

Comment: I can confirm I'm having the same issue. In my case I open a file with `readImage()`, crop it using `cropImage()`, resize it using `resizeImage()` and then write it using `writeImage()`. The file is created exactly as I'd expect, cropped and resized, and `getImageWidth()` and `getImageHeight()` return the correct values. However, `getImageLength()` always returns `0`.

Comment: @Bison so you can try the way i found. use strlen( $image->getImageBlob() ) to get the file size. it seems returns a correct value.

Comment: @LCB At the moment I'm just using the standard PHP `filesize()` function. I prefer that to the `getImageBlob()` solution because it doesn't need to load the entire image into RAM (which can obviously have a big impact on your server if this concurrently happens with lots of files). It does cache the results though, so look at `clearstatcache()` if you need to call it more than once on the same file.

Comment: @Bison after you crop the image with cropImage method of Imagick, the image has already loaded into RAM ? isn't it ?

Comment: @LCB Yes, you do have a point there. I suppose that if you have not loaded it into Imagick yet `filesize()` is faster, but if you already have the image read I don't know. Ideally I'd write a performance test for this, but I don't have the time right now. I might still do that this weekend.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I think I found out the way to get the file size after cropping the image.

Using `strlen( $image->getImageBlob() )` will always return the correct value.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the Imagick library only calculates the length after the image has been output in some way. If you call `$image->getImageLength()` *after* previously calling `$image->getImageBlob()`, it will return the correct value.